# Google Analytics for tracking search values in android

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking

In my android application, I have a search functionality. I would like to track the search keywords that my users search for. As far as I know, Google Analaytics could track events in my android app. I was wondering if it could do the same for search items.

If it is possible, a sample code or a link would be great!

Answer (score 0):

That's mostly a question of how to segment your data in the Analytics web app, almost a science in itself.
Example:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent("Search", "Keywords", searchString, 1L);
```

Remember the basic usage of EasyTracker:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/

Answer (score 0):

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", this);
```

After defining tracker, you should call the below method.

```
public static void trackEventGoogle(String category,String action,String label,int value)
{
    try
    {
        GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance().trackEvent(category,action,label,value);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        exceptionLog(e);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. Don't forget to add analytics jar file to your project.